# Get AWS Instance Types, Accelation Types via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to build couple of JSON documents based off of the information thats available on aws pricing site: Before I go through the painful attempt of parsing the pricing page (https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/), Is there a better API where I can get information related to all the instances to build a document as following:

```
    {
    "ml.t2.medium": {
    "vCPU": 2.0,
    "mem_GiB": 4.0,
    "GPU_mem_GiB": null,
    "network_performance": "Low to Moderate",
    "category": "Standard",
    "GPU_count": 0,
    "GPU_type": null
  },
```

Comment: [describe-instance-types — AWS Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html) -- It lists EC2 instance types, not SageMaker, but they are presumably the same.

Answer (score 0):

The method described above is the best way to do it progmatically, either from the CLI or via the SDK.

In addition, if it's just SageMaker Studio notebook instance types you're looking to extract, a simple to parse web page can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html

Likewise, if it's EC2 instance types you want to extract, the data can easily be parsed from this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#AvailableInstanceTypes

Both of these could easily be used to extract the data manually if it's just a one-off extract you need, or if you use Python, a package such as Beautiful Soup would help to automate the process: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Neither page contains all of the additional instance type information you're looking for, but you could retrieve this using the describe-instance-types call answered above, by combining it with the --filters sub command, with parameters for, eg: NVMe support, encryption support, default-vcpus, etc. I'm not aware of any API call that tells you everything about every instance types, it looks like iterating through the filter types is the only way to do it.